# Convergence or divergence of the series $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm taking undergrad real analysis. I'm trying to come up with a general formula for the series
\begin{equation}
1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+...
\end{equation} and cannot understand how to get the negative term to only show up with powers of $3$. Or is there another way to test the series. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number with the convention $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$, then the $n$th term here is $\dfrac{(-1)^{F_n+1}}{n}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partial sums of this series can be bounded below by partial sums of the series $$1+\frac14+\frac17+\frac1{10}+\cdots$$ which in turn can be bounded below by the partial sums of the series $$\frac13+\frac16+\frac19+\frac1{12}+\cdots=\frac13\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots\right).$$

The latter series is a constant multiple of the harmonic series, hence it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{align} 
&\quad\, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}\color{red}{-}\frac{1}{3n+3}\right] \\[2mm] 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}\color{red}{-}\frac{2}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+3}\right] \\[2mm] 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}\color{red}{-}\frac{2}{3n+3}\right]+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{3n+3}\right] \\[2mm] 
&= \log{3}+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \color{red}{\,\,\rightarrow\,\,\infty} \\[2mm] 
\end{align} $$